# How can I make the check button work in CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've tried to design the checkbtn using css but its failing to work. The check psuedo elements and the hover elements seem not to be working, am actually trying to make a hamburger button for the navigation any ideas on how to fix this code?

```css
.checkbtn {
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.header .navbar {
  flex: 1;
}

.header .navbar ul {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  top: 72px;
  right: -100%;
  transition: all .5s;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.header .navbar ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.header .navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

*these hover psuedos don't work as well.*
 .navbar ul li a:hover,
a.after {
  background-color: none;
  color: darkred;
}


/* This psuedo element is failing to work */

#check:checked~.ul {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="burger">
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn">&#9776;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO, can you please provide your HTML code too

Comment: Showing us a bit of CSS on its own is rather pointless, without the HTML it is supposed to apply to.

Comment: Here is the HTML.   <div class="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#Index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#About-us.html"> About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Coffee.html">Coffee</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Farmers.html">Farmers</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Contacts.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="burger">
   <label for="check" class="checkbtn">&#9776;</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: To start, your a.after needs to become a:after to be a pseudo-element. Your supplied HTML also has one too many </div>'s at the end - although that might be a copy-paste error

Comment: I made you the snippet I asked for. Also fixed your hrefs and added an extra link. Pleasse correct the code to make the [mcve] I asked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar ul li a:hover ,a.after{
```

in this line you have a.after - this is looking for an anchor tag "a" with a class of "after". If you meant to use the psuedo-element :after it should be a::after in CSS3 (or a:after in CSS2 - both will work) as mentioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

For the checkbox you have:

```
#check:checked ~ .ul{
```

You are using the General Sibling Combinator "~". This is what MDN says about this:

> The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches
> all iterations of the second element, that are following the first
> element (though not necessarily immediately), and are children of the
> same parent element.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

In your HTML there are no unordered list tags **after** the checkbox. This means CSS doesn't find any elements to style. The checkbox needs to be **before** the  tags which you want to affect and **within the same parent tag** (ie. they need to be "siblings").

Note: You can still position the checkbox to appear elsewhere using CSS

Comment: Thank you Jacob. Let me try to correct all that.